# Something about this past tense rubs me wrong, pls help

Tags: past-tense

Imagine this sentence:

> Alice snapped to attention. Wait, what? Did Bob really say what she think he said?

Autocorrect says **think** should be **thought**, but I am not sure.

Also, it feels to me the first **say** should **said**, regardless of **did**, but that is maybe just my mother tongue messing with me.

Comment: Your mother tongue has messed with you twice, because 'say' is correct. 'Did' is followed by the bare infinitive (so **did** _someone_ **say** _something_?) and also it looks like 'Wait, what?' is what Alice thought (in the past) at the time she _snapped to attention_ (did you mean that in the military sense?)

Comment: snapped to attention - I meant that she started to pay attention. 
Are you saying the correct tenses are Did Say Thought Said?

Comment: Yes, 'snap to attention' can be used figuratively that way. Literally it is what soldiers do when they move quickly to a position of standing silently with the body stiff and straight, the feet together, and both arms at the sides. And yes that is what I am saying.

Comment: The entire sentence is Past Tense, so it has to be *Alice **snapped** to attention. Wait, what? Did Bob really say what she **thought** he said?* If it was Present Tense (about something that's happening at time of speaking) it would be *Alice **snaps** to attention. Wait, what? Did Bob really say what she **thinks** he said?* It's always Past Tense ***did** Bob really [say that]?* because whatever Bob said, he said it *before* Alice's reaction. Note that ***think*** can *never* be valid in this context.

Comment: "Alice snaps to attention. Wait, what? Did Bob really say what she thinks he said?"

I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks for everything!

Comment: I'm confused by both the down vote and the close vote. This question seems to me clear, and unlikely to be quickly resolved by personal research.

Comment: [correction of idiom: rubs me the wrong way] Cheers.

Comment: @AndyBonner We are seeing way too many close votes for things that should not be closed. I wonder if those who answer have trouble seeing it from the OPs point of view. Of course, duplicates should be closed but many others should not.

Comment: @Lambie Meh, I have bigger problems with the downvotes. Aside from the fact that both are felt, especially by newcomers, as punitive and personal aggression, *ideally* the cv is "As it stands, this question isn't ready for good answers; let's shut it down before people throw on *bad* answers, and invite the OP to edit, at which point we retract or reopen." While dv is "Hey everybody, this question isn't worth your time, don't even bother looking." Which is way more valuable on a site with incredibly high traffic like SO, and often amounts to petty wrist-slapping elsewhere.

Comment: @Lambie I dv with a clear conscience when an active user with reputation over 1K posts something blatantly OT, but I try to be more gracious to anyone under that. I go ahead and cv when appropriate, though, with a gracious explanation.

Comment: @AndyBonner I agree with all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenses get confusing because we can be talking about multiple points in time at once.

- The whole story is being told in the past tense. Let's say that it happened yesterday.
- "Alice snapped to attention"—let's say this happened at 10:00.
- When did Bob say something? Earlier than 10:00. Maybe only seconds earlier, but it was already earlier on the time line, say 9:59 and 50 seconds. So, as we tell this story today, we're talking about "past Alice" who even in her time is looking "back in time" to Bob's comment. That's why "he said" is past tense. Meanwhile, we use "say" in "did Bob say," *but it's not really present tense*. We use the past tense "did" along with the main verb when we ask a question. "I swam yesterday" -> "Did you swim yesterday?"
- "She thought": This one is a bit ambiguous, but it doesn't matter. Either it means that at the moment Bob spoke, she had a thought about his meaning (9:59:50), OR it means that between the speaking and this moment in the story she formed a thought about his meaning (9:59:55), OR it means that at this moment, as she snaps to attention, she has a thought about his meaning (10:00). Either way, it's all in the past from our storytelling point of view, so past tense is fine, and in this case these 10-second differences don't matter to the story.

As suggested in your comment, you *could* move the whole story to present tense; sometimes stories are told that way. In that case it would be "snaps," present tense. We would still use "did Bob say," a past tense construction, because it happened earlier than the sentence. We could choose *either* "... what she thought he said," meaning that she formed a thought as he spoke, OR "... what she thinks he said," meaning that she's thinking about it right this second. Either is fine and has little change to the story. For me, I feel like "what she thought he said" feels more natural to this sentence, though if I were to speak in first person, I could easily imagine saying *either* "Did you just say what I *think* you said" or "... what I *thought* you said."

Comment: It would be useful (for me at least), if you could write out in full the way you see the sentences. Thanks.

Comment: I see you managed to write all that without getting distracted by ***Had** Bob really **said** what she thought he [**had**] said?* Which is perfectly valid, even with ***had*** repeated - but that's the kind of construction most learners need to learn to ***avoid***, because they've been erroneously taught to overuse Perfect verb forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Had Thad had what she had thought he had had?" :D

Comment: I'm sure there's an example somewhere of a syntactically valid utterance with some ridiculous number of consecutive instances of the word ***had***. But unlike the ***buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo...*** one (which tramples over the normal rules of capitalization), the ***had had had had...*** one depends on mixing "use" and "mention".